# Using Strings instead of double/long for line chart in achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I want to plot a XY line graph with some double values on Y axis and some String values on X axis. But the XYSeries takes only double/long values. So,is there any way I can use a string array on the X axis?

Thanks for any suggestions.

code:

```
  //fDates are strings

 XYSeries fPriceseries = new XYSeries("Fuel prices");
     for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
     {
         long fDate = Long.parseLong(fDates[i]);    
         fPriceseries.add(fDate, fPrice[i]);
     }
     XYSeries fMileageSeries = new XYSeries("Mileage");
      for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
      {
          long fDate = Long.parseLong(fDates[i]);   
          fMileageSeries.add(fDate, fMileage[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Post your code to clarify.

Comment: @Badaro I have posted the code, though it doesnt parse the string into long, hence I need to know if i can use the String directly without parsing them

Comment: I not understood, Double.parseDouble(yourString) don't solve it?

Comment: @Badaro I did not try it with double because my Strings are the dates like 14/08/2013

Comment: @Badaro As i said I have saved my dates as Strings, so I dont knw how to use it with TImeSeries

Comment: Well, you can change the code to use/save your dates as Date or use SimpleDateFormat to parse your date string to Date object.

Comment: @Badaro Guess Ill have to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TimeSeries:

**fDates as Date array**

```
 TimeSeries fPriceseries = new TimeSeries("Fuel prices");
 for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
 {
     fPriceseries.add(fDates[i], fPrice[i]);
 }
 TimeSeries fMileageSeries = new TimeSeries("Mileage");
  for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
  {
      fMileageSeries.add(fDates[i], fMileage[i]);
  }
```

**fDates as String array - Using SimpleDateFormat.**

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

 TimeSeries fPriceseries = new TimeSeries("Fuel prices");

 for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
 {
     fPriceseries.add(sdf.parse(fDates[i]), fPrice[i]);
 }
 TimeSeries fMileageSeries = new TimeSeries("Mileage");
  for(int i=0;i<fDates.length;i++)
  {
      fMileageSeries.add(sdf.parse(fDates[i]), fMileage[i]);
  }
```

Referencies:

http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/model/TimeSeries.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Than you so much for your answer. Your second code did the trick. I have one more issue that when I scroll the chart the dates disappear and reappear when I scroll back to the original position

Comment: Also is the x axis displayes the time too, I do not want that can I only display the date in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot plot a graph using string on any axis.

Explanation:

When we plot a graph we compare two values... as in 3,5 or 7,22 or 12.3,10000..

**Plotting string with respect to an integer or double,is like comparing apples and oranges.**

So m sorry friend but its not possible.. unless you convert the string or create a reference for its contents..

Comment: thanks for replying. i solved the issue with Badaros solution. But I have another issue I have one more issue that when I scroll the chart the dates disappear and the x axis displayes the time too, I do not want that can I only display the date in some way? Can u suggest something

Comment: you re welcome..i haven't done much programming in android.. but still.. u may check if there is anyway to dynamically refresh the screen through you program, as soon as you plot the graph.. or maybe you can dynamically plot the graph repetitively until user exits..

Comment: I guess that happened because my dates were very close to each other. Also I replaced  ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, format) with ChartFactory.getTimeChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer, format, activityTitle) which shows only dates not the time. Thank you again

Comment: if this same problems occurs to me someday..this will help! thanks